# Deploying Multiple wars and handling theirs dependencies

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, architecture, dependencies

I have 5 .war files deployed in tomcat 7 that uses common 3 rd party jars for now.

I use shared/lib for putting depended jars for all wars. The problem with this approach is that If i want to change the dependency of the one of the war i need to update all 5 wars dependencies. This seems to be very bad practice of deploying app.

From the application perspective, it is guaranteed that all 4 wars will have always have same dependencies and only one war can have different dependency down the line.

So I've decided to use common(shared) lib for 4 wars and WEB_INF/lib for 1 war instead of using common for all to avoid resource.  Is it possible to set different class lib path for different wars by configuration somehow ?

Comment: Why every war using its separate copy of dependency jars is not an option? Since I have seen you tagged your question with Maven, I do thinks it's just a matter of several lines of change with dependency scope.

Comment: @JerryTian I don't have control on 4 wars (obtained from different team/project). I have control over only one war. So I can't change dependent 4 wars.

Comment: Ok, if I understand you correct, you don't need to set different class path(or I would rather say you can't). According to J2EE spec, every WAR has its own class loader, which has high priority than application server's, and you can safely put jars in whatever WAR's WEB/lib. For the magic behind this, I recommend you read this article: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html